# How to make gradient colors with C# in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Recently I have been looking for solutions about making a rainbow gradient in visual studio, all I have come across is with the use of the rand function, which I do not want, as it is random colors. Is there a way to make a nice cycling gradient in visual studio?

Thanks,
Phillip.

Comment: Using what? Winforms? What sort of control? WPF it would be a cinch for most controls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a rainbow color gradient in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2288498/10263)

Comment: Have a look at this http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/map-numeric-values-to-colors-in-a-rainbow-in-c

Comment: I am looking for a way to make a gradient, sort of like the one showed in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUeF-Onx7Hc Except not with the rand function, with a defined set of colors cycling through the rainbow.